# Asterisk real time database

Tags: asterisk

The register statement in `sip.conf` allows your Asterisk server to register with a provider.

Is it possible to put this register statement into a realtime database and update it in realtime?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? How about just placing the file in a place where it can be updated remotely?

Comment: whenever a user registers i need the user details to be updated in my DB. @DennisJaheruddin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you read upon the extconfig.conf file, used especially for this:

```
;
; Static and realtime external configuration
; engine configuration
;
; See https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Realtime+Database+Configuration
; for basic table formatting information.
;
[settings]
;
; Static configuration files:
;
; file.conf => driver,database[,table[,priority]]
;
; maps a particular configuration file to the given
; database driver, database and table (or uses the
; name of the file as the table if not specified)
;
;uncomment to load queues.conf via the odbc engine.
;
;queues.conf => odbc,asterisk,ast_config
;extensions.conf => sqlite,asterisk,ast_config
```

Regards,
Mirko

Comment: I want it to be dynamic. @mirkobrankovic

Comment: this should be exactly that :)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to follow this all steps.

1) Write below code at last or you can put the value in [general] section in the file /etc/asterisk/res_config_mysql.conf

```
 [general]
 dbhost = 127.0.0.1 
 dbname = [dbname]
 dbuser = root 
 dbpass = [dbpass]
 dbport = 3306
```

2) Write below code in /etc/asterisk/extconfig.conf

```
iaxusers => mysql,general,cc_iax_buddies 
iaxpeers => mysql,general,cc_iax_buddies
sipusers => mysql,general,cc_sip_buddies
sippeers => mysql,general,cc_sip_buddies
```

3) Check the mysql status

```
    cli> realtime mysql status
```

4) If modules are not added then add from source file like below

```
cd /root/download/asterisk/asterisk-1.8.1.12.1 (Path of asterisk source)
make menuselect
*app-mysql
*res_config_mysql.conf
exit(esc)
make
make install
```

5) /etc/asterisk/sip.conf
uncomment rtcachefriends=yes like below

```
rtcachefriends=yes
;rtsavesysname=yes
rtupdate=yes
rtautoclear=yes
```